# Seahorse / GNOME Keyring does not recognize my new ed25519 SSH key, is there another way to have the key unlocked upon login?

Tags: ssh, key-authentication, gnome-keyring, seahorse

I am unsure if I did the whole procedure right, so let's start with what I've done:

```
$ ssh-keygen -vvv -o -a 1000 -t ed25519 -f ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 -C "$(whoami)@$(hostname)--$(date -I)"
```

with some real strong password.

I successfully logged into my Debian machine using that key (`-i /path/to/private/key`).

I thought that's a success, so I've rebooted both machines and now my GNOME Keyring is empty on both Mint and Debian with me being unable to manually import the private key, I tried it:

[image: me being unable to manually import the private key]

I have found that Seahorse (GNOME Keyring) currently does not handle Ed25519 on [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME/Keyring#Cannot_handle_ECDSA_and_Ed25519_keys):

The following citation was edited to be more up-to-date and to have various links to the Wikipedia and to be more readable.

> As of January 2018, `seahorse` (GNOME Keyring) doesn't handle **ECDSA** {[Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=641082) (*RESOLVED FIXED*), [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm)}, nor Ed25519 {[Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=723274) (*NEW*), [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdDSA#Ed25519)} keys. You can turn to other SSH agents if you need support for those.
>    ([Source - look at the bottom](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME/Keyring#Cannot_handle_ECDSA_and_Ed25519_keys)).

---

Do I need to wait for a bug fix / enhancement, or is there an alternative approach for me not to have to enter the complex password or enter it maybe once upon login? I don't honestly know, what my choices are at the moment.

---

### EDIT #1

I don't want to switch back to the [ECDSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm) or [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) keys.

### EDIT #2

I have installed Linux Mint 19.1 (clean install, no upgrade), which is based on Ubuntu 18.04, but the issue in the same manner persists.

The `ed25519` does not show up in the Seahorse 3.20.0:

[image: <code>ed25519</code> does not show up in the Seahorse]

---

Listing keys:

```
for key in ~/.ssh/id_*; do ssh-keygen -l -f "${key}"; done | uniq
```

- Server:

  ```
  256 SHA256:SMeBXPSluFwGBub/brKUy4/m8/DLim8Aw7zMmcdyEPs root@backup-server--2019-02-22 (ED25519)
  8192 SHA256:JKKvLs+LXOdgv5nr00YFGjywqGANEFwCjXnzcjJ87og root@backup-server (RSA)
  ```
- Client:

  ```
  256 SHA256:WOj0Nl4svbiSxayTOCUC9LlI5nPQDyls9qV65u/0WwE vlastimil@dell-7577--2019-02-22 (ED25519)
  8192 SHA256:GWPe50O7U0xq3DsRaQewz4WhOLrZ64Vf4x5bKnelrX4 vlastimil@dell-7577 (RSA)
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seems to have been resolved in Ubuntu 20.04 based systems like my Linux Mint 20 (Cinnamon) ([download & info link](https://linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=281)).

---

My `seahorse` is of version `3.31.91` there with the `ed25519` keys showing up already:

[image: seahorse 3.31.91 ed25519 showing]

---

Only to note, I previously tried to manually compile the `seahorse` on Linux Mint 19.x and that also worked in GUI. However, I did not use it, so I can't confirm / disprove such an approach to be actually functioning.

Answer (score 0):

[ssh-ed25519 is not supported in gnome-keyring](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-keyring/-/issues/112) as of today.

A workaround is to [use a different ssh-agent implementation in your session](https://eklitzke.org/using-ssh-agent-and-ed25519-keys-on-gnome).

Answer (score -1):

The fix for this issue is included in [Gnome Keyring 3.28](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-keyring/tree/NEWS?h=gnome-3-28) and seems unlikely to be backported to earlier versions.  If you want to persevere with Ed25519, then you will need to wait for a release of your favourite distribution that includes this version.  I see that the next release of Linux Mint, [Tara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint_version_history#Release_history), will be based on Ubuntu 18.04, which [includes this version](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/gnome-keyring), so perhaps you will not have too long to wait.

Comment: I am using vanilla Arch Linux with Gnome 3.30, and it's still not working here.

Comment: There's also a [Debian bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=928668) for this against 3.28.

Comment: May be common knowledge, but I fought Seahorse trying to get it to recognize and import my ed25519 key. Finally found that I didn't have id_ed25519.pub (the public key) in my .ssh folder. As soon as I created that via 'ssh-keygen -y -f id_ed25519 > id_ed25519.pub', on my next SSH attempt I was prompted and asked if I wanted to import the key and unlock it on login.

So simply not having your pubkey in your .ssh directory alongside the private key prevents Seahorse from using the key at all.